# Fatal Error <fcntl.h> No such file or directory

Tags: compiling, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
fatal error: fcntl.h : No such file or directory
    2 | #include<fcntl.h >
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I am facing this problem while iam compiling file containing fcntl.h header file when using open system call in my  c program in Ubuntu (its windows subsystem linux)

I have tried all possible ways/answers given on this askubuntu .com and  on other sites, but error is still here. When I execute the following command it displays 6 instead of 45

```
 dpkg -S fcntl.h| wc -l
6
```

Comment: I think you need to `apt install linux-libc-dev`. But, why are 
you showing us the line count of the `dpkg` command output and not the command output itself?

Comment: Thank you Sir but I got this msg now:    ~$ apt install linux-libc-dev
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

Comment: You should put `sudo ` in front of the `apt ...` command.

Comment: You want `libc6-dev` for the userland `/usr/include/fcntl.h` I think (it will pull in `linux-libc-dev` as a dependency)